# Massive Memory Leak in SwiftUI for macOS

Tags: macos, memory-leaks, swiftui

I've pretty much completed creating my first macOS SwiftUI app. It's working fine but after using it for more than 10 minutes I noticed a dramatic slow down and big memory footprint. I condensed the problem down into the following minimal example, which is a full SwiftUI app for both macOS and iOS.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @State var selection: Int?
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                List(0...10, id: \.self) { element in
                    NavigationLink(destination: VeryComplexView(text: "\(element)"),
                                   tag: element, selection: $selection) {
                        Text("\(element)")
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct VeryComplexView: View {
    let text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { _ in
                List(1...5000, id: \.self) { element in
                    Text("\(text) \(element)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't expect performance to be great, because it's really quit a big View, but I would expect performance to stay consistent and no memory leaks. But on macOS after just a few clicks in the NavigationView I'm getting a memory footprint of 1GB and performance decreases. Profiling the app with Leak Detector also shows a massive amount of leaks in SwiftUI classes. Compiling the same app for iOS stays at a reasonable footprint of 50 MB even after using it for a while. This bug prevents me from properly using my app. Are there workarounds?

I'm running the latest Big Sur 11.2.1 and Xcode 12.4

Comment: Keep in mind that memory management for a Debug build or on a Simulator is not real memory management. Only a Release build checked in Instruments, on a device not a Simulator, can tell you what's happening.

Comment: thanks @matt Yes, I tested this with release build in Instruments

Comment: What happens with `LazyHStack`?

Comment: @CenkBilgen seems like the leak is gone when using `LazyHStack` but the layout looks different ( I need to add `.frame(minWidth: 100)` to the `List` to make it visible` ) Also when I change it to a `ZStack` I have the leak back and there's no lazy replacement for that. Can't imagine that I'm not missing something here, it practically makes SwiftUI unusable for macOS.